# How to send @user.password by email for "Forgot password?" if using has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to send an email through ActionMailer for users who forget their passwords. They type in their email and press submit, and it's supposed to send them an email with their password in the email. However, since I have has_secure_password I'm guessing that the password_digest is not allowing me to extract the password. I received an email that said:

```
Your login information:

Email: edmai@syr.edu

Password:
```

So it looks like rails is doing something to stop me from taking out the password. Here are my files:

email template:

```
Dear <%= @user.name %>,

<p>
    You recently made a request for a lost password. Please remember to keep your passwords recorded in a safe place.
</p>

<p>
    Your login information: <br>
    Email: <%= @user.email %> <br>
    Password: <%= @user.password %> <br>
</p>

<p>
    Sincerely, <br>
    Pholder Staff
</p>
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_secure_password
attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :profilepic
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
```

let me know if you need any more of my files

Comment: you should reset the password. It's not safe otherwise

Comment: I don't use rails but unless has_secure_password does something different from the name, the password is hashed, not encrypted or plain text. This means you cannot send the user their password because you don't have it, you only have a secure hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`has_secure_password` hashes your users password with bcrypt. This is so that a plain text password is not stored in your database (something which should never, ever happen). Some info on the method is here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html

Like @apneadiving said, you need to reset the password and send the user a password reset link.

Watch these two Railscasts in order, they might help you out:

1. http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1
2. http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password